# Streaming my music from OneDrive to my phone

Tags: music, onedrive, xbox-music, streaming

I uploaded music to the Music folder on OneDrive. I understand that I'm supposed to be able to stream this music to my Nokia Icon (WP 8.0) but I don't see the music anywhere in the Xbox Music app. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or is this an 8.1 thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is now available (as of March 2015). Any music files in supported formats (MP3, M4A and WMA) you add to your OneDrive Music folder can be streamed through Xbox Music on your phone, PC, Xbox or the web player.

For more information see [Blogging Windows](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/03/18/access-your-personal-music-collection-from-onedrive-with-the-xbox-music-app) and [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-to-access-music-collection-onedrive-xbox-music).

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using **[Metro File Manager](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=eb83936a-6e24-4729-ba17-2100870ec17b)** and stream directly from any OneDrive folder.