# What is streaming in music -> album -> showing

Tags: 8.1, music

What is streaming option available in Music -> alubum -> showing. I am using Window phone 8.1.

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That option is for playing music that is not on your device (as opposed to the "On My Phone" option). Currently, such music can come from two sources:

1. [The Xbox Music catalogue](https://music.xbox.com)
2. [The Music folder on your OneDrive](https://music.xbox.com/Onedrive) (see also [this answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/5300/1401))

Obviously, in both cases an internet connection (whether WiFi or cellular) is required. The first option additionally requires an [Xbox Music Pass](http://www.xbox.com/music/music-pass) subscription.